# Libiconv C++ Builder

Tags: c++, windows, c++builder, iconv

I'm currently trying to integrate the ZBar library to an application built in C++ Builder (XE6). However, the ZBar library depends on iconv which is not originally available in Windows, so I managed to get a static library of iconv for windows : "libiconvStatic.lib".

Then I tried to import it to my project this way (I'm not sure the first line is necessary though) :

```
#define USING_STATIC_LIBICONV
#include <iconv.h>

#pragma comment (lib, "libiconvStatic.lib")
```

The functions from iconv which are called in the file are **iconv_open()**, **iconv()** and **iconv_close()**.

I get through the compilation but get an error from the linker :

> [ilink64 Error] Fatal : Invalid object file '/72'

I already tried with both 32bits and 64bits versions of the libiconvStatic.lib .

Do you know why the .lib is not recognized and how to solve this problem? Or any other way to make use of iconv in Windows (and C++ Builder) ?

Thank you.

Comment: How did you create "libiconvStatic.lib"? Was it created also with C++Builder, or with some other compiler?

Comment: I downloaded it, it was compiled with MVSC. Is it incompatible?

Comment: Yes, libraries or objects created with other compilers are not compatible with the C++Builder ones, at least most of them. I guess that is the cause of your problem. If you can rebuild the library with C++Builder then it should work. Alternatively, you could use a dynamic version of that library, and just implib the lib needed for C++Builder from the DLL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in comments: you should build the library with C++Builder directly, as the object file format is different between MSVC and C++Builder.

Alternatively, you could build a dynamic version of the library with MSVC, and just do `implib libiconv.lib libiconv.dll` to generate a C++Builder compatible library from the DLL.